# ¿Como puedo traer los 'datos' de mi db filtrando por el id de una persona?

Tags: javascript, spring

Buenas tengo una tabla `personas` con una relacion `oneToMany` , y otra tabla `personemergencycontacts` , es decir una persona puede tener muchos contactos de emergencia, la cuestion es que en el `modal` de `contactos de emergencia` no se como traer solo los contactos de esa persona, me trae todos los registros.

```
methods: {
  getData() {
    this.$axios.get('persons/' + this.person_id).then((response) => {
      this.form.person = response.data;
    });
    this.$axios.get('personemergencycontacts' ).then((response) => {
      this.allData = response.data;
      this.loading = false;
    });
  },
```

Puedo usar esta consulta para hacer un join con el id de `personemergencycontact` ? Efectivamente uso spring mvc

```
 @GetMapping("/persons/{id}")
public ResponseEntity getPersonById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long personId) {
    try {
        Person person = service.findById(personId);
        if (person == null) {
            LOGGER.warn("PersonController | Imposible obtener entidad, no existe registro con identificador: " + personId + ".");
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(new responseMessage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(), null, "No existe persona."));
        }
        LOGGER.info("PersonController | Identificador solicitado: " + personId + ".");
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(person);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(new responseMessage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(), e.getMessage(), getLocaleMessage("error.internal_error")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Una de las muchas soluciones esta en el backend, tienes que hacer la consulta por el id de la persona y combinarla con la otra tabla dependiendo al id que sea igual, puedes implementar un `JOIN`

Comment: gracias, sabras de algun ejemplo?

Comment: No se vé qué código manejas para extraer los datos filtrados por el id de la persona. Tu código hace pensar que usas algún framework, si es así conviene que lo digas y que incluso pongas una etiqueta del mismo en la pregunta.